# bash shell wildcard pattern matching

Tags: shell, unix, filtering, wildcard

How could I filter the text and match the lines having dd, Capital letter followed by 2 character. 4 digits, for example, "20,Apr.2014", "2,Mar.2013" using bash shell only. No sed or awk.

Comment: Better give a sample input/output and provide us your attempts !

Comment: What have you tried? Also the examples are not what you describe you want to match. Special characters make a difference.

Comment: @Grice the answer is below and it works in a way I want to match the lines starting with "20,Apr.2014". Dont need to overcomplicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat fileName | grep -E '^[0-9]{1,2},[A-Z][a-z][a-z].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

This will match "20,Apr.2014", "2,Mar.2013" pattern. {1,2} means one or 2 digits.

Comment: You could make additional use of `{}` to make it a bit shorter - `'^[0-9]{1,2},[A-Z][a-z]{2}.[0-9]{4}'`. Not sure that makes it any clearer, or has any other benefits, but it is slightly less typing...

Answer (score 1):

This wildcard should do it:

```
[0-3][0-9],[A-Z][a-z][a-z].{19,20}[0-9][0-9]
```

It only allows years in the 20th and 21st centuries, I think it's obvious how to expand that.